# How does the company give permission to the analytics developer to access the company's twitter data?

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, analytics, twitter-oauth

I've been asked to provide client_id and client_secret so that a 3rd party can make a client_credentials grant_type-request to twitter and so do some analytics on our twitter traffic.

If this were Google Analytics or Adwords, I'd go to the relevant panel and add the 3rd party's developer. What do I do for Twitter?

These one answer I've received so far suggests that I need to create my own app and give the other guy the stuff produced by the app-generator. This doesn't make a lot of sense.

**PLEASE NOTE**

I am ***not*** asking from the point of view of the developer but from that of the company on whose behalf the analytics are being performed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and log in, if necessary
2. Supply the necessary required fields, accept the TOS, and solve the CAPTCHA.
3. Submit the form
4. Copy the consumer key (API key) and consumer secret from the screen into your application

If you also need the access token representing your own account's relationship with the application:

1. Ensure that your application is configured correctly with the permission level you need (read-only, read-write, read-write-with-direct messages).
2. On the application's detail page, invoke the "Your access token" feature to automatically negotiate the access token at the permission level you need.
3. Copy the indicated access token and access token secret from the screen into your application

Be sure and configure your application as needed before attempting the "your access token" step.

Comment: So, the third party has already created an app and they have their consumer key and consumer secret. I create an app and generate a consumer key and consumer secret. I give these to the third party and they use their key and secret to connect to twitter and then use my key and secret when requesting a client_credentials connection to my data.

Is that what you mean?